# A part of div were hidden by relative div

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I've made a drop down menu. It should appear by clicking on the button inside an `absolute` positioned `div`.

Works great, but IE8 hides a part of menu that appear under the bottom border of an `absolute` positioned `div`.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the code (without js): http://jsfiddle.net/cQcJ5/1/

Can somebody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE8 to test but it sounds like a z-index issue on either the header or in the menu somewhere.

Comment: no, unfortunately z-index can't help :(

I can add more height to header div and the menu starts to appear

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a DOCTYPE declaration at the start of your markup?

Try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
```